# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar

I have a spark cluster with 4 nodes and i try to start app:
`spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --class "Init" --master spark://host /home/cassandra/spark2Cassandra-assembly-0.1.jar` - this doesn't work even if i add this: `--jars /home/cassandra/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar`

Also, i tried to assembly my app with all dependencies inckuding  `com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder`

```
libraryDependencies += "com.twitter" % "jsr166e" % "1.1.0"
```

Also, i tried to add this jar into all nodes' spark\jars dir - this didn't work for me

How can i distribute this jar to my cluster?

Full error (the same message many times):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/twitter/jsr166e/LongAdder     at
>   org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$TaskMetricsSupport$class.$init$(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$TaskMetricsUpdater.(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.metrics.OutputMetricsUpdater$.apply(OutputMetricsUpdater.scala:75)
>     at
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.writeInternal(TableWriter.scala:174)
>     at
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.insert(TableWriter.scala:162)
>     at
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:149)
>     at
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
>     at
>   com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:36)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)  at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

**UPDATED**

If i use local mode and start it via:

```
spark-shell --jars /data/tmp/spark-cassandra-connector-2.0.5-s_2.11.jar,/data/tmp/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar
```

It works, but the same doesn't work for cluster mode

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was in SPARK_HOME environment variable which wasn't defined on nodes

Answer (score 6):

Download `jsr166e.jar` from maven repo if you don't have it and
copy `jsr166e.jar` file to `SPARK_HOME/jars/`(on all spark node) and try again.it's work for me.

Comment: I didn't believe before trying, but this worked like a charm, for me!

Comment: Worked for me too. Regards, Marius

Answer (score 0):

Download jsr166e.jar from maven repo if you don't have it and copy jsr166e.jar file to SPARK_HOME/jars/(on all spark node) and try again.
it's work for me.

If you are using the spark job server on container Spark home point to /opt/spark/ ,put the downloaded jar in /opt/spark/jars folder on the container.

With docker on kubernetes you also use below command to directly put the jar

kubectl cp .m2/repository/com/twitter/jsr166e/1.1.0/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar spark-jobserver-787bf78797-6v24j:/opt/spark/jars/jsr166e-1.1.0.jar -c spark-jobserver